# How can I undo a previous commit without force push?

Tags: git

Let's say I remove a line from a file and I commit and push that change:

**commit 4dd87**

```
$ vim myfile.txt //remove line from file
$ git add myfile.txt
$ git commit -m "line added"
$ git push origin master
```

Now, I make another change and I push it:

**commit 84674**

```
$ vim myfile.txt //make another change, whatever
$ git add myfile.txt
$ git commit -m "another change"
$ git push origin master
```

Now, I want to recover the line that I removed in first commit. I would do it with the next steps:

1) Go to commit previous to remove the line (previous to 4dd87) with `git reset --hard 4dd87`
2) Apply changes of second commit with `git cherry-pick 84674`
3) Force push with `git push origin master --force`

But there are many drawbacks using this approach when there are more people pushing to the repo.

So, is there a better way?

Comment: Use `git revert`, which creates a new commit that reverts the changes made in the original one.

Comment: @Thomas Great, that's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: note that, although it is an improvement over OPs solution, it is not ideal to make another commit if you just want to restore the file. Also `git revert` can not single out a file, if you have multiple files committed. Lastly it does not really help if there are have been multiple commits and you want to see how your file was before them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), which creates a new commit that reverts the changes made in the original one.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is this: check out file from previous commit:

```
git checkout 4dd87 myfile.txt
```

now you have your file back the way it was in 4dd87, and ready to be committed, or you can modify it further.